# Closed questions you voted for closure show as deleted in votes section

Tags: bug, profile-page, closed-questions, vote-to-close

In my profile's `votes` tab, under the `closure` option, I see this:

[image]

The closure votes marked with `(deleted)` actually haven't been deleted. Those are the ones that have been closed.

Doesn't it seem like this isn't right? Or do close votes all the sudden count as delete votes but don't actually delete anything?

It's a bug. It needs to say `(closed)`

Comment: It's not indicating that the *question* was deleted, but rather the vote. This is probably more confusing than necessary in the case where the vote was successful instead of just expiring, however.

Comment: @Tim So are you saying it shouldn't just say `(closed)`?

Comment: Right, that status is unrelated to the question itself. It's just saying you cast a vote on that question, and the vote is no longer pending (it expired, or, in your case, resulted in the question being closed; both cases are considered as the vote itself having been "deleted").

Comment: @TimStone I think it used to say (closed). I'm still thinking it should be (closed) and (expired).